# "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY" when trying to add bootstrap-ui to my angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bower

I am trying to install angular-ui

I have tried all the commands from the tutorials, including:

```
npm install angular-bootstrap
```

This returns the arror

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@>=1.5
```

I checked my angular version and it is 1.4, so I am assuming that is the reason ?

I read a tutorial about migrating to 1.5 but it simply says that I should copy the new link to angular.js 1.5, which I did. Still no luck.

Comment: Can you show us the `js` imports?

Comment: Pretty sure angular-bootstrap should support v1.4.x is there another package you are including which might require v1.5?

Answer (score 0):

**UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY** error is thrown when the dependencies of one or more modules specified in the package.json file is not met.

You need to install peer dependencies manually, just do an npm install on the needed deps, and then try to install the main one again.

```
npm install -g
npm install angular-bootstrap
```